# Illogical Results from Cucumer/Arquillian Test with H2

Tags: jpa, cucumber, h2, jboss-arquillian

I am having an issue where I am attempting to create a Cucumber/Arquillian test for a new service that performs a batch update with JPQL. Everything seems to work correctly, except my `@Then` code validating the change.

I am setting up my test data in my feature file and it gets added to the H2 database that is created in memory for each test. When the batch update runs it reports back the expected update count based on that data. But when I retrieve one of the objects that should have been updated, the data on that object appears to be unchanged.

Please note: When I execute the service call in my application against our Oracle database it works correctly and the table is updated as expected. The problem seems to be with caching on the H2 in memory database.

My datasource that gets deployed to JBoss by Arquillian is:

```
<datasource enabled="true"
            jndi-name="jdbc/arquillian" 
            pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedH2Pool">
   <connection-url>
      jdbc:h2:mem:arquillian;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST_DB
   </connection-url>
   <driver>h2</driver>
</datasource>
```

My Cucumber test defines `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "localH2-testDB")`

My persistence.xml contains:

```
<persistence-unit name="localH2-testDB">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I don't know what other settings for the H2 database I can change to try and eliminate any caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is inherent to how batch updates are handled in JPA. They do NOT update the persistence cache as one might expect. So the tables were updated correctly, but when the object was re-queried, it didn't have the updates. This is why my test was failing (everything was inside the same transaction) and my deployed code worked (separate transactions performing the update and re-querying the data).